# Android Google Drive Api token error

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I am having trouble integrating Google drive into my android app.

I would like the ability to upload,download and browse files.

So far I am just trying to retrieve a list of files using the Java API for drive since Google says it is more flexible.

I am connection to Google Drive like so:

```
googleAccountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(getActivity(), Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE));
    googleAccountCredential.setSelectedAccountName(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE).get(0));
    //startActivityForResult(googleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
    driveService = getDriveService(googleAccountCredential);
```

And after that i am trying to get a list of files:

```
private List<File> retrieveAllFiles(Drive service) throws IOException {
    List<File> result = new ArrayList<File>();
    Files.List request = service.files().list().setQ("trashed = false");
    this.logMessage("Attempting to get files");
    this.logMessage("Size of reply is: "+request.size());
    do {
        try {
            FileList files = request.execute();
            result.addAll(files.getItems());
            request.setPageToken(files.getNextPageToken());
            this.logMessage("Got files. Size is: " + result.size());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            this.logMessage("Error: " + e);
            request.setPageToken(null);
        }
    } while (request.getPageToken() != null &&
            request.getPageToken().length() > 0);

    return result;
}
```

This is the error it gives:

```
Process: com.some.package, PID: 12439
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
        at android.accounts.Account.<init>(Account.java:48)
        at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential.getToken(GoogleAccountCredential.java:255)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.extensions.android.gms.auth.GoogleAccountCredential$RequestHandler.intercept(GoogleAccountCredential.java:279)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:859)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
        at com.some.package.Thing.DriveManager.retrieveAllFiles(DriveManager.java:144)
        at com.some.package.Thing.DriveManager.loadAccount(DriveManager.java:121)
        at com.some.package.Thing.DriveManager.onCreateView(DriveManager.java:95)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
        at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:447)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue, did you manage to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I forgot what exactly was wrong, so listed the whole process the way i do it.

First check if there is an account in the `SharedPrefrences`

```
SharedPreferences settings = fragment.getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    googleAccountCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
            fragment.getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(SCOPES))
            .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff())
            .setSelectedAccountName(settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, null));
```

If there is no account, the name returned by `settings.getString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME` will be null.

So call the account choose method

```
private void chooseAccount() {
    fragment.getActivity().startActivityForResult(googleAccountCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
}
```

In the `onActivityResult` we check.

```
 if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null &&
                    data.getExtras() != null) {
                String accountName =
                        data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                if (accountName != null) {
                    credential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);
                    SharedPreferences settings =
                            getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
                    editor.putString(PREF_ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName);
                    editor.commit();
                }
            }
```

Now you have the acount you need, but must authorize it.

I found no other way to launch the authorization activity other than to list the files, use the method listed above, but the try will be a little different.

You also need to catch

```
catch (UserRecoverableAuthIOException e){
                               fragment.getActivity().startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), 
REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
}
```

After this your app should have full access to Google Drive.

if you are still having trouble check this [link](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/quickstart/android)